# Why does a GET index/_doc/entry return nothing? Not an error, not even an "_index", "_id", "_version" metadata, but really nothing?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, pdf

I would like to ingest this pdf:
https://kerlaz.bzh/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/Compte-rendu-conseil-04-09-2023.pdf

I've created an index (1) and ingested it (2) successfully. I believe.

Then, if I search for the entries stored in the `comptes_rendus_municipaux` index where I've put it, *Kibana* console lists it:

```json
GET comptes_rendus_municipaux/_search?pretty=true
{
 "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  },
  
  "size": 9000, 
  "stored_fields": ["_id"]
}
```

```json
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "comptes_rendus_municipaux",
        "_id": "29090-2023-09-04",
        "_score": 1,
        "_ignored": [
          "attachment.content.keyword",
          "data.keyword"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if I attempt to see the entry `29090-2023-09-04` in the `comptes_rendus_municipaux` by a `GET comptes_rendus_municipaux/_doc/29090-2023-09-04`, Kibana console displays nothing.

Not an error, not something starting with:

```
{
  "_index": "comptes_rendus_municipaux",
  "_id": "29090-2023-09-04",
  "_version": 1,
  "_seq_no": 1,
  "_primary_term": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "data": "JVBERi0xLjUKJdDU..."
```

I could expect.
But really nothing. Why?

(1) The way I've created my index

```json
PUT comptes_rendus_municipaux/
{
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attachment": {
        "properties": {
          "author": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "french",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "content_length": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "content_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "creator_tool": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "format": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "keywords": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "language": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "modified": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(2) The way I've ingested it

script `index.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export source=$1
export index=$2
export entree=$3

# Le paramètre source doit être alimenté
if [ -z "$source" ]; then
   echo "Le nom du fichier pdf à indexer dans Elastic est attendu en paramètre." >&2
   exit 1
fi

# Si le fichier source n'a pas d'extension, lui rajouter celle .pdf
if [[ "$source" != *"."* ]]; then
   source=$source.pdf
fi

# Il doit avoir l'extension pdf
if [[ "$source" != *".pdf" ]]; then
   echo "Le fichier à indexer dans Elastic doit avoir l'extension .pdf" >&2
   exit 1
fi

# Si l'index n'est pas alimenté, lui assigner apprentissage
if [ -z "$index" ]; then
  index=apprentissage
fi

# Si l'entrée n'est pas alimentée, lui assigner le nom du fichier sans extension
if [ -z "$entree" ]; then
  entree=$(basename "${source%.*}")
fi

host="http://localhost:9200"
user="elastic"
pwd="Ox-JoQT0po=pdOT-LeE*"

json_file=$(mktemp)
cur_url="$host/$index/_doc/$entree?pipeline=attachment"

echo '{"data"  : "'"$( base64 "$source" -w 0    )"'"}' >"$json_file"
# echo "transfert via $json_file vers $cur_url"

if ! ingest=$(curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "$user:$pwd" -d "@$json_file" "$cur_url"); then
  echo "Echec de l'ingestion dans Elastic de $source dans l'index $index, entrée $entree : $ingest" >&2
  exit $?
fi

rm "$json_file"
echo "$source indexé dans l'entrée $entree de l'index $index d'Elastic"
```

run with the command line:

```bash
index Kerlaz-Compte-rendu-conseil-04-09-2023 comptes_rendus_municipaux 29090-2023-09-04
```

with a successful output:

```
Kerlaz-Compte-rendu-conseil-04-09-2023.pdf indexé dans l'entrée 29090-2023-09-04 de l'index comptes_rendus_municipaux d'Elastic
```

Comment: Can you also show the response you get when running `GET comptes_rendus_municipaux/_doc/29090-2023-09-04` ?

Comment: @Val there is no response. This is the problem. No reaction. The cursor only goes the line below after a ten of second, without writing anything. If I change the GET, typing `GET comptes_rendus_municipaux/_doc/29090-2023-09-0` (omitting a character) I will receive an error. But with `GET comptes_rendus_municipaux/_doc/29090-2023-09-04` it accepts the command but responds nothing.

Comment: Which version of the stack are you running ?

I tried to repeat it with `POST _bulk
{"index": {"_index": "77695950", "_id": "29090-2023-09-04"}}
{"data": "plop"}


GET /77695950/_doc/29090-2023-09-04`

And it works perfectly.

I am running the version 8.11.1

Comment: @Paulo I'll check in few hours (I'm not on the good computer), but I should have the latest coming with debian upgrades, the same as yours, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Epilog:**
On my `8.11.3`, If I execute it through a `curl`, it works:

```bash
curl  -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -u "elastic:Ox-JoQT0po=pdOT-LeE*" 
   "http://localhost:9200/comptes_rendus_municipaux/_doc/29090-2023-09-04"
```

```json
{"_index":"comptes_rendus_municipaux","_id":"29090-2023-09-04","_version":1,"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":{"data":"JVBERi[...]",,"attachment":{"date":"2023-09-06T10:37:50Z","content_type":"application/pdf","format":"application/pdf; version=1.4","language":"fr","content":"[...] le conseil municipal, à l'unanimité, émet un avis favorable aux propositions ci-dessus.\n\n10\n\n\n\nFD/05/09/2023 12:24\n\nDeliberation   2023 - 39\nRapport annuel d'activité de Douarnenez Communauté 2022\n\nRapporteur : Mithée HERNANDEZ\n\nConformément à la réglementation, un rapport annuel d'activités, visant à renforcer l'information des habitants de Douarnenez-\nCommunauté, est adressé aux maires de chaque commune du territoire de Dz Co avant le 30 septembre.\n\nCe rapport retrace l'activité de la communauté et fait l'objet par le maire d'une communication au conseil municipal en séance\npublique.\n\nIl est proposé aux élus de prendre connaissance de ce rapport.\n\nLa Secrétaire de séance :\n\nSylvie LELOUP\n\nLa Maire,\n\nMarie HERNANDEZ\n\nLa Maire\n\nMarie HERNANDEZ\n\n11","content_length":29535}
```

a single line of 4.6 MB size (the original pdf is 3.4 MB)

I may be in front of a *Kibana* behavior, that doesn't display anything, apart from a `200 - OK`, because the response is too large.

[image]

But no clearer warning from it is disturbing.